# Intellisense for Typescript Definitions does not work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The intellisense for lodash doesn't work for me. The 'require' word in my editor is white instead of blue.

Here is a screenshot:

http://postimg.org/image/blwiyo7ep/

I can run the program so everything fine but the js intellisense. Can anybody help me? (Windows 10, VSC 0.10.5, Node 4.1.1 )

Comment: Node v5.4.0, tsd 0.6.5, and lodash 3.10.1. For me as well, intellisense is working with other required modules but doesn't work for lodash.